# What are the file annotations in a pip requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, pip, remote-desktop

My general Python workflow, which has been restricted to my own Windows laptop so far, involves using `conda` to manage environments and install packages.

However, I now need to work on a project from a remote desktop as well. That remote desktop has `python3` and `pip` installed, but I cannot install `conda` (and I do not want to). I decided to uploaded the required packages to my repository, so that I can correctly run my project on the remote desktop.

**To get to the point**: since I do not have `conda` installed on the remote desktop, I used `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate a requirements file on my laptop (that I uploaded to my repo), hoping to use `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the remote desktop. However, the `requirements.txt` file contains package annotations of the format `package-name @ file:///some/directory`, which makes the package installation fail on the remote desktop.

What do the `@ file:///...` annotations mean, why are they generated, and is there a way to just get the package versions in the `package-name==package-version` format instead, so that I can install them using `pip` on my remote desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out this command :

```
 pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

For more information read this [github discussion](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8174#issuecomment-621649797)